# Error when trying to run Omnet++ simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am new to Omnet++ and I have downloaded some code from GitHub and I am just trying to run it on instant veins and I keep getting an errors with 'VeinsInetMobility.h'. The downloaded code has it's own 'veins_inet' folder, so when I replace 'VeinsInetMobility.h' from the downloaded code with the 'VeinsInetMobility.h' provided by instant veins, it still produces an error (see the 2 errors attached).

Anybody have any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMScC.png) [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTypr.png)

Link to code: https://github.com/chaotictoejam/VANETTutorials

Comment: You said you downloaded „some code from GitHub“, but maybe you could also reveal which code exactly? This would make it easier to reproduce the error

Comment: Here is the GitHub link: https://github.com/chaotictoejam/VANETTutorials

Comment: Thanks! From the README of the project you linked it seems like very specific versions of INET, Veins and SUMO are needed. Which versions did you use?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I have figured out the problem and I am able to run the simulation! Thanks for your help! You were right, it had something to do with the version of INET being used. Another quick question here... Would you know (or have seen any implementations online) how to implement a Vehicle-to-Infrastructure model by editing this code?

Comment: Glad to hear it! Would you mind posting (as the correct answer to your question) what you needed to do? I can imagine that a lot of other people might run into the same problems, so you could help a lot of people!